# Where can I find a list of Search Engine Settings variables?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm wondering where I can find a list of what every variable is in the Search Engine settings.

When you input a Search Engine into the settings, there are a number of variables attached, for example:

- **%s** - The search query you're running
- **inputEncoding** - The input encoding (i.e. UTF-8)
- **RLZ** - ???
- **baseURL** - ???
- **assistedQueryStats** - ???

Comment: related question regarding the AQS parameter http://superuser.com/questions/653295/what-is-the-aqs-parameter-is-google-search-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome takes advantage of **OpenSearch**, "a collection of simple formats for the sharing of search results", as their specification for search query handling. The specification can be found **[here](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_URL_template_syntax)**. But this only applies to any terms that are not prefixed with "google:". Because "google:" prefixed variables are subject to change, it is best to, at this time, reference directly to the source code of the URL management, which can be found **[here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090422083538/http://src.chromium.org:80/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/search_engines/template_url.cc)**. The source code is also subject to change.

- **"google:" prefixed** search variables can be found **[here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090422083538/http://src.chromium.org:80/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/search_engines/template_url.cc)**.
- **All other** search variables can be found **[here](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_URL_template_syntax)**.